# A div is inheriting it's parent's width which is not what I want

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make the div's width the same as the width of the image inside of it and ignore the width of the parent? My wrapper is 1200px, my image container's width is not set and the image inside the container is not hard coded so I can't hard code the width of the image container. I wanna make the image container wrap around the image and have the same width as it. Any way to do that?

```
    <?php
        include 'header.php';
        include 'includes/comments.inc.php';
        include 'includes/images.inc.php';
    ?>
    <div class="wrapper">

    <?php

        $imagePath = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        $realImagePath = substr($imagePath, 1);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE path='$realImagePath'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $getResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        echo "<div class='imageContainer'>"
                        ."<h1>".$getResult['name'].'</h1>'
                        .'<div class="relativeContainer"><img class="uploadedRealImg" src="uploads/'.$realImagePath .'" alt="Random image" /></div>'."<br><br>"
                        .$getResult['description']."<br><br>"
                        .$getResult['date']."<br><br>"
                        .$getResult['author']."<br><br></div>";

                            if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                                $id = $_SESSION['id'];
                                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$id'";
                                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                                $getResult2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

                                    if ($getResult2['username'] == $getResult['author']) {
                                        echo "<form method='POST' action='".deleteImage($conn)."'>
                                                <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$getResult['id']."'>
                                                <input type='hidden' name='path' value='".$getResult['path']."'>
                                                <input type='hidden' name='author' value='".$getResult['author']."'>
                                                <button id='delImage' type='submit' name='imageDelete'>Delete Image</button>
                                            </form>";
                                        }
                                }

        echo "<form method='POST' action='".setComments($conn)."'>
                <textarea class='commentSection' name='message'></textarea><br>
                <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Comment</button>
            </form>";

    ?>

    <div id="comments">
        <?php
            getComments($conn);
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php
        echo "<button id='moreComments'>Show more comments</button>";
    ?>

</div>
<?php
    include 'footer.php';
?>

css

    .wrapper {
        width: 63.1%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .imageContainer {
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    .uploadedImg {
      width: 500px;
      height: auto;
    }
    .uploadedRealImg {
      max-width: 1200px;
    }
    .commentSection {
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
    }
    #delImage {
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
    }
    .relativeContainer {
      position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: Show us your HTML and CSS please

Comment: I've done that but as you can see it has PHP in it as well.

Comment: This is way too much code. You can just show a small example of the very bare minimum markup and CSS to get your use-case across.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.imageContainer` is a `div`, and a `div` is a [block element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements). Block elements try to fill 100% of their parent width.

You can change `.imageContainer` to an `inline-block`, which fits it's contents.

```css
.wrapper {
  background: purple;
}

.imageContainer  {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid gold;
}

.image {
  display: block; /** optional - if you need the imageContainer height to be the same as that of the image
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <img class="image" src="https://a.wattpad.com/useravatar/ReaderOfTheReads.256.435663.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. One of the ways is setting `display: table` to the image container, and make sure that the `<img>` element has `display: block`. I put together an example below. Notice the red border of the image container.

```css
#wrapper{
  width: 1200px;
}
.image-container{
  display:table;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.image-container img{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/avatar300s/a96ecf5e524449ec866a6674709bb212.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would warn against using table elements or display rules for anything that isn't tabular data.

Comment: Which would you say are the risks of using i.e. `display: table;` on an element that isn't actually a table containing tabular data? @sheriffderek

Comment: I just think it's a hack. Building truly responsive layouts force a different mindset. Tables are for tabular data, just like lists are for list items.

Answer (score -1):

Try the !importent tag after the css you want to force apply.

i.e: css: mycssproperty!important;

Comment: you should look that `!important` up. I've had to use it in many situations - but if you aren't working on a legacy codebase with many conflicting plugins with CSS & and it isn't 100% THE ONLY way to go... you shouldn't use it. So - basically never. Reasons being that it can't be over-written - and in the world of 2017, style-sheets must actually cascade for many more reasons than they used to. : )